# A traversal as data

Tags: haskell

I heard about this construction which is loosely described as “a traversal represented in data, applied to some structure, without the need for the applicative”

It can be defined as:

```
data X a b r =
    | Done r
    | Step a (X a b (b -> r))
```

A word description would be as follows:

- the type `X a b r` describes the shape of a structure
- which contains things of type `a`
- and for each `a` you get the opportunity to produce something of type `b`
- and provided you do that for each `a`,
- you get something of type `r`.

Thus a “traversal” of a list, `[a]`, has type `X a b [b]`, because if you can turn each `a` of the list into a `b` then you get a `[b]`.

**My question is**: what is this thing called? Is there a reference to more information about it?

---

Example usage:

```
instance Functor (X a b) where
  fmap f (Done r) = f r
  fmap f (Step a next) = Step a (fmap (f .) next)

f :: [a] -> X a b [b]
f [] = Done []
f (a:as) = Step a (fmap (flip (:)) as)

g :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> X a b r -> f r
g f (Done r) = pure r
g f (Step a next) = g f next <*> f a
```

More generally:

```
instance Applicative (X a b) where
  pure x = Done x
  Done f <*> y = fmap (\y -> f y) y
  Step a next <*> y = Step a (fmap flip next <*> y)

t :: Traversable t => t a -> X a b (t b)
t = traverse (\a -> Step a (Done id))
```

And, assuming I haven’t made any errors, we should find that:

```
flip g . t == traverse
```

---

Edit: I’ve thought about this some more. There is something this doesn’t have which a `traversal` has: a `traversal` can split up the computation into something that isn’t “one at a time,” for example to traverse a binary tree one can traverse the left and right half “in parallel.” Here is a structure that I think gives the same effect:

```
data Y a b r =
  | Done r
  | One a (b -> r)
  | forall s t. Split (Y a b s) (Y a b t) (s -> t -> r)
```

(Slightly vague syntax as I don’t remember it and don’t want to write this as a gadt)

```
f1 :: X a b r -> Y a b r
f1 (Done x) = Done x
f1 (Step a next) = Split (One a id) (f1 next) (flip ($))

f2 :: Y a b r -> X a b r
f2 (Done x) = Done x
f2 (One a f) = Step a (Done f)
f2 (Split x y f) = f <$> f2 x <*> f2 y
```

Comment: It vaguely resembles an [iteratee](https://wiki.haskell.org/Enumerator_and_iteratee), but the type above uses the `b ->` in a different place, exploiting polymorphic recursion (unlike an iteratee).

Comment: As far as further reading material goes, a good starting point could be [*Trading FunLists at a Bazaar with Yoneda*](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2018/10/12/trading-funlists-at-a-bazaar-with-yoneda/) at Bartosz Milewski's blog.

Comment: An `Iteratee` gets given a bunch of values and can build up whatever it wants, whereas this gives you values and you get to step through the computation that builds up a result in the same shape.

Comment: It reminds me of the notion of a “[smart] view” from [A Smart View on Datatypes](https://www.fceia.unr.edu.ar/~mauro/pubs/smartviews/smartviews.pdf).

Comment: Could this type be a basis for a library like [foldl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.5/), but of composable traversals instead of folds?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia possibly but they don’t really compose the way folds do. It’s sort of clear to me that if you have a fold for the sum and a fold for the count then you can compose into a fold for the (sum, count) and so get the average. However I’m not sure how such traversals should compose. Perhaps this would be a useful way to express how to traverse over a composition of data structures, but why not just compose `traverse` with itself a sufficient number of times?